# Can you use mutiple Xlib Display connections and multiple eglDisplay connections in one application

Tags: opengl, x11

One to One sharing of Display to eglDisplay.
No sharing of windows or surfaces.
Is it possible? Are there any gotchas I should know about?

Comment: Which EGL implementation are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can have as many `Display` connections as you wish in your program. The only potential problem is getting events from many connections simultaneously. You can't just use `XNextEvent` for that like in a normal single-display application. You need to extract `ConnectionNumber` from each `Display`, put them in an `fdset` and wait for an event with `select` (on POSIX systems at least). Then call `XNextEvent` on a connection that `select` reports ready.

I'm not sure about `eglDisplay`, but given that it can be obtained from `Display`, I'd say there should be no problem.